# Inserting columns with subquery/join

Tags: sql, join, insert, apex

I am having troubles to insert correct data into my tables. I have tables as below:

Here are tables with data:

•   Theatre(Theatre#, Name)
•   Trow(TR#, RowName, RowType, Theatre#)
•   Tseat(TS#, SeatNo, TR#)
•   Season(Season#, SeasonName, Year)
•   Production(P#, Season#, Title)
•   ProductionRun(P#, Theatre#)
•   Performance(Per#, P#, Theatre#,Weekday)
•   Client(Client#,name )
•   TicketPurchase(Purchase#, Client#, Per#,TotalAmount, TS#)

My tables are for example as below:

•   ProductionMy(P#,Title)

Into this table I would like to insert columns **P#** and **Title** from table **Production** and to insert only rows where column Per# from table Performance matches column Per# in table TicketPurchase

Another table for example is :

•   TimeID(TimeID,Month,Year,Weekday,SeasonName)

I would need to insert unique instances of time from table Performance and **SeasonName** from **Season** table based on criteria if **Per#** in **Performance** table and **Per#** in **TicketPurchase** table matches. I tried for example below with no success:

insert  into  time  select time_seq.nextval,month,year,weekday,SeasonNAme from 
(select distinct
extract(month from pDate) month, 
extract(year from pDate) year,
Weekday,
SeasonName 
from Performance, Season);

Or another example .I have table:

**TRowMY**(TR#,RowType)

I would like to insert here data from **RowType,TR#** columns in **RowType** table based on the criteria that TS# column in **TicketPurchase** table matches **TS#** column in **TSeat** table.

Or another example, my table:

ClientMy(Client#,Name)

I want to insert columns **Client#,Name** from column **Client** only when **Client#** in **Client** table matches **CLient#** in **TicketPurchase** table.

Basically I need to insert data that has been involved in ticket sales as not all performance, seasons, or productions/clients that are in tables are in the **TicketPurchase** table.

I really stuck in here, please could you at least help me with some tables, so that I will have idea who to deal with rest, please.

Hope i have explained this well...

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like this.

```
INSERT INTO ClientMy(id, name)
SELECT Client#,Name FROM Client AS C1 WHERE Client# IN (SELECT Client# FROM
TicketPurchase WHERE Client# = C1.Client#)
```

Maybe I am wrong, but I think I didn't fully understood what you wanted.